# Replace While() loop with Timer to prevent the GUI from freezing [Multithreading?]

Tags: multithreading, flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, timer

How can I use the Timer class and timer events to turn this loop into one that executes chunks at a time? 
My current method of just running the loop keeps **freezing up the flash/air UI.**

I'm trying to acheive psuedo multithreading. Yes, this is from wavwriter.as:

```
// Write to file in chunks of converted data.
    while (dataInput.bytesAvailable > 0) 
    {
        tempData.clear();
        // Resampling logic variables
        var minSamples:int = Math.min(dataInput.bytesAvailable/4, 8192);
        var readSampleLength:int = minSamples;//Math.floor(minSamples/soundRate);
        var resampleFrequency:int = 100;  // Every X frames drop or add frames
        var resampleFrequencyCheck:int = (soundRate-Math.floor(soundRate))*resampleFrequency;
        var soundRateCeil:int = Math.ceil(soundRate);
        var soundRateFloor:int = Math.floor(soundRate);
        var jlen:int = 0;
        var channelCount:int = (numOfChannels-inputNumChannels);
        /*
        trace("resampleFrequency: " + resampleFrequency + " resampleFrequencyCheck: " + resampleFrequencyCheck
            + " soundRateCeil: " + soundRateCeil + " soundRateFloor: " + soundRateFloor);
        */
        var value:Number = 0;
        // Assumes data is in samples of float value
        for (var i:int = 0;i < readSampleLength;i+=4)
        {
            value = dataInput.readFloat();
            // Check for sanity of float value
            if (value > 1 || value < -1)
                throw new Error("Audio samples not in float format");

            // Special case with 8bit WAV files
            if (sampleBitRate == 8)
                value = (bitResolution * value) + bitResolution;
            else
                value = bitResolution * value;

            // Resampling Logic for non-integer sampling rate conversions
            jlen = (resampleFrequencyCheck > 0 && i % resampleFrequency < resampleFrequencyCheck) ? soundRateCeil : soundRateFloor; 
            for (var j:int = 0; j < jlen; j++)
            {
                writeCorrectBits(tempData, value, channelCount);
            }
        }
        dataOutput.writeBytes(tempData);
    }
}
```

Comment: And why can't you just add the timer with some delay?

Comment: Because it would attempt to still use the whole ByteArray of recorded audio. I need a way to split up dataInput into chunks of bytes...

Comment: Can you give me whole calss code to make good understaning of your code to give proper solutions? I have idea and alredy i implemented many times these things.

Comment: This is the whole class: http://code.google.com/p/ghostcat/source/browse/trunk/ghostcatfp10/src/ghostcat/media/WAVWriter.as?r=424 I would really appreciate anyone helping convert this class to a more CPU friendly one. Infact, I'm sure a large portion of the Flex community would be appreciate it! Thanks for taking a look @Mrugesh

Comment: I attempted to turn the wavwriter class into a recursive method which calls itself using callLater(), but it's not working :/ The new method is called lateWrite(i:int); Here's my try: http://pastebin.com/qb2pUw7U
I think I need to take a different approach...maybe better chunking, or use of timers...?

Comment: In this week-end I will try...

Answer (score 0):

I have once implemented pseudo multithreading in AS3 by **splitting the task into chunks**, instead of splitting the data into chunks.

My solution might not be optimal, but it worked nicely for me in the context of performing a large Depth-First Search while allowing the Flash game to flow nicely.

- Use a variable **ticks** to count computation "ticks", similar to CPU clock cycles. Every time you perform some operation, you increment this counter by 1. Increment it even more after a heavier operation is performed.
- In specific parts of your code, insert checkpoints where you check if **ticks** > **threshold**, where **threshold** is a parameter you want to tune after you have this pseudo multithreading working.
- If ticks > threshold at the checkpoint, you save the current state of your task, set ticks to zero, then exit the function.
- The method has to be retried later, so here you employ a Timer with an **interval** parameter that should also be tuned later.
- When restarting the method, use the saved state of your paused task to detect where your task should be resumed.

For your specific situation, I would suggest splitting the tasks of the **for** loops, instead of thinking about the while loop. The idea is to interrupt the for loops, remember their state, then continue from there after the resting interval.

To simplify, imagine that we have only the outmost for loop. A sketch of the new method is:

```
WhileLoop: while (dataInput.bytesAvailable > 0 && ticks < threshold) 
{
  if(!didSubTaskA) {
    // do subtask A...
    ticks += 2;
    didSubTaskA = true;
  }

  if(ticks > threshold) {
    ticks = 0;
    restTimer.reset();
    restTimer.start(); // This dispatches an event that should trigger this method
    break WhileLoop;
  }

  for (var i:int = next_unused_i;i < readSampleLength;i+=4) {
    next_unused_i = i+1;
    // do subtask B...
    ticks += 1;
    if(ticks > threshold) {
      ticks = 0;
      restTimer.reset();
      restTimer.start();
      break WhileLoop;
    }
  }

  next_unused_i = 0;
  didSubTaskA = false;
}
if(ticks > threshold) {
  ticks = 0;
  restTimer.reset();
  restTimer.start();
}
```

The variables **ticks**, **threshold**, **restTimer**, **next_unused_i**, and **didSubTaskA** are important, and can't be local method variables. They could be static or class variables. Subtask A is that part where you "Resampling logic variables", and also the variables used there can't be local variables, so make them class variables as well, so their values can persist when you leave and come back to the method.

You can make it look nicer by creating your own Task class, then storing there the whole state of interrupted state of your "threaded"-algorithm. Also, you could maybe make the checkpoint become a local function.

I didn't test the code above so I can't guarantee it works, but the idea is basically that. I hope it helps